# RxAndroidBle work with not low energy devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, rxandroidble

Is there any possibility to work with non-low-energy devices using RxAndroidBle library?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `RxAndroidBle` stands for `RxJava Android Bluetooth Low Energy` and is not intended to work with non–BLE devices.

Fortunately enough there is a quite similar and interesting library wrapping standard Bluetooth Android API — [RxBluetooth](https://github.com/IvBaranov/RxBluetooth).